# Upload image in S3 bucket: A "region" configuration value is required for the "s3" service

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS-SDK. After installing the package  getting following  error:

> Missing required client configuration options: region: (string) A "region" configuration value is required for the "s3" service (e.g., "us-west-2"). A list of available public regions and endpoints can be found at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html. version: (string) A "version" configuration value is required. Specifying a version constraint ensures that your code will not be affected by a breaking change made to the service. For example, when using Amazon S3, you can lock your API version to "2006-03-01". Your build of the SDK has the following version(s) of "s3": * "2006-03-01" You may provide "latest" to the "version" configuration value to utilize the most recent available API version that your client's API provider can find. Note: Using 'latest' in a production application is not recommended. A list of available API versions can be found on each client's API documentation page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/index.html. If you are unable to load a specific API version, then you may need to update your copy of the SDK.

wp-config file added:

```
define('AWS_S3_KEY', '%xx%');

define('AWS_S3_SECRET', '%xx%');
```

Still showing that message I think needs to add further configuration. Let me know if you have any solution it will be helpful.

Comment: Can you edit your Question to show the code that is generating this error?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying hat you have not provided a value for the `region`.

Here is some sample PHP code from [Creating and Using Amazon S3 Buckets with the AWS SDK for PHP Version 3 - AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-examples-creating-buckets.html):

```php
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
        'profile' => 'default',
        'region' => 'us-west-2',
        'version' => '2006-03-01'
    ]);
    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $key,
        'SourceFile' => $file_Path,
    ]);
```

Comment: 'Key' => $key, here I need to put the URL of s3 where the upload image will go  right sir?

Comment: You would need to provide a `Bucket` name, and a `Key`. The `Key` is the destination path + filename in the S3 bucket, such as `invoices/January.txt`. Note that it includes the path (if desired). The folders are created automatically (sort of).

Answer (score -1):

I can understand this is late but here is my solution....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88oIL.png)

You will have to set the default region value on the server. I hosted mine on heroku.

I hope

Comment: On Stackoverflow if you want to give solution then you have to add code not just comment.

Comment: Okay, this is well noted. Apologies.